# OLEDBCommand handle missing database row

Tags: vb.net, oledbcommand

I have 2 tables, products, and author, the author table has a column that relates to the product table by an ID so I have done a select statement below to get the right rows based on the ID's. However the author table might not have any data in and therefore no ID to the product table. If this is the case then the information from the product doesn't show up.

So my question is how do i handle this?

```
    Dim ID As String = Request("id")
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID) Then
        Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx")
    End If

    Try
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(strcon)
            conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As String = "SELECT * FROM tblProducts, tblPrdAuthor " & _
                                "WHERE tblProducts.ID = " & ID & " AND tblPrdAuthor.paPrdID = tblProducts.ID"
            Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn)
                Dim ds As New DataSet()
                da.Fill(ds)

                'Bind to the repeater
                rptProduct.DataSource = ds
                rptProduct.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from table1 as A left outer join table2 as B on (A.id=B.id) where a.id=101 and b.pid=102
```

Comment: Maybe I didnt explain myself properly. The blPrdAuthor.paPrdID may not exist in the second table for some of the products but for other products the information will exist in the table so effectively i want a way to show just the information from the product table if there is no relating ID in the author table

Comment: using left ouver join if exist then taking otherwise not taking

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this originally but with an INNER JOIN.